# get a variable row from a while mysql_fetch array that isnt the last result

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, session-variables

Hey guys I'm having a hard time sending a session variable of the $row['projectnaam']
 that belongs to the one that just has been clicked.
 At the moment the Session always takes the last $row['projectnaam'] 
from the while loop and I'm wondering how I can send the right 
variable with a session that belongs to the row that just has been clicked.

Thank you in advance.

Here's my syntax:

```
<?php
include "config.php"
$bedrijfsnaam = $_SESSION['gebruikerbedrijf'];
 $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE bedrijfsnaam='$bedrijfsnaam' ")or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $_SESSION['projectnaam'] = $projectnaam;
    header('Location: viewprojectsbedrijf.php');
}
     echo "<div class='project'>";
     echo "<div class='projectdetails'>";
     echo "<p class='projectnaam'>";
      echo $row['projectnaam'];
      echo "</p>";
      echo "<hr class='paars'>";
      echo "<p class='datum'>";
      echo $row['datum'];
      echo "|";
      echo $row['Tijd'];
      echo "</p>";
      echo "<hr class='paars'>";
       echo "<p class='bedrijfsnaam'>";
      echo $row['bedrijfsnaam'];
      echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
       echo "<div class='view'>";
       echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\">";
      echo "<input type='submit' value='View' name='submit' class='viewbutton'></input>";
     echo "</form>";
        echo "</div>"; 
 }
?>
```

Comment: So you want $row['projectnaam'] to be $_SESSION['projectnaam'] when clicked 'submit'?

Comment: I would like $_SESSION['projectnaam'] to be $row['projectnaam'] of the row that has been echoed in the same parent div as the button that has been submitted

Comment: so where $projectnaam is now, $row['projectnaam'] should be read:)

Comment: Then you must have $row['projectnaam'] in your form so it will be posted, which isnt the case now. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mede Nederlander ;)

I think you mean to do something like this:

```
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['projectnaam'] = $_POST['projectnaam'];
    header('Location: viewprojectsbedrijf.php');
}
$bedrijfsnaam = $_SESSION['gebruikersbedrijf'];
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projecten WHERE bedrijfsnaam=".$bedrijfsnaam)or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<div class='project'>
    <div class='projectdetails'>
    <p class='projectnaam'>
    <form method=post action=''>
    <input type=text value=".$row['projectnaam']." name=projectnaam>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
    </form>";   
}
```

In your own script only your submit button is in the form, so that will be the only value posted. In that case you won't get the POST value of 'projectnaam'.
Also, you try to make a SESSION value of a variable which isn't declared in your posted code. In my code it makes a Session value of the POSTED code.

Comment: Im getting Notice: Undefined index: projectnaam if I try using the post

Comment: $_POST['projectnaam'] = $_SESSION['projectnaam'];  must be $_SESSION['projectnaam']  = $_POST['projectnaam'];

Comment: that seemed to help, only the input value now is stopped after a space, so while $row['projectnaam'] returns a value like New B, the SESSION returns only New

Comment: Change <input type=text value=".$row['projectnaam']." name=projectnaam> into this:  <input type=text value='".$row['projectnaam']."' name=projectnaam>